# Read, Write, Notify of Core Bluetooth Framework

Tags: iphone, core-bluetooth

Hope you would be fine. Am working on a iOS project and connecting with a car using BLE112. 
I am having some confusion in writing the BGProfile. I have read the BGProfile developer guide but still I  am confused with the properties read, write, notify.

The scenario is simple. When i press a start button on my iPhone car should start. So which property should i used here for characteristic?
As only job would be to just access that Port that is connected to start Button. .

I shall be very thankful

Answer (score 2):

> When i press a start button on my iPhone car should start. So which property should i used here for characteristic?

This will be defined in the documentation for the Bluetooth profile you are using.  This is probably proprietary information, so I doubt anybody here can tell you.

Comment: There is no profile available. I have to write a custom profile for it. If you know about any exsisting profile help me with it. I shall be really greatful

Comment: I can't teach you the Bluetooth protocol in Stack Overflow comments.  Read the documentation for the BLE112 and maybe a book on Bluetooth.  Apple's developer account also includes some helpful videos.

Answer (score 0):

Your idea is super but you need to know some basic information about bluetooth LE.

First - bluetooth LE can speak only to another bluetooth LE. Check weather your car bluetooth and iPhone bluetooth are both LE.

Second - your car bluetooth system should have the capability to start your car.